# vim on mac /V stops at the first occurrence of '/'

Tags: search, vim

vim on mac `/V` stops at the first occurrence of `/abc`
e.g.

```
/\Vthis/is/a/path
```

would stop searching/matching after `/`

Any clues?
I am not looking to d

```
:let @/="this/is/a/path"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if searching string with `/` is your question, you could

- use `/`, and escape the `/ -> \/`
- use `?`, like `?this/is/foo/bar` then `N`

usually I would take the 2nd option.

Comment: Curious as to why searching with a ? search for '/' without having to escape it?

Comment: yes @Sumonto you have to escape each `/` when you search by `/`. but `?`, you can just type `/`...